# How can I achieve this with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I would like to group all messages between 2 people in a group (chat). Doesn`t matter if I am the author or receiver.

Let's say this example code.

```
const messages = [
  { id: '100', text: 'aaa', author: { id: '1' }, receiver: { id: '2' } },
  { id: '101', text: 'bbb', author: { id: '2' }, receiver: { id: '1' } },
  { id: '102', text: 'ccc', author: { id: '3' }, receiver: { id: '1' } },
]
```

Imagine, I am user ID = 1, so I would like to get this:

```
const chats = [
  {
    chatName: 'Name of user ID 2', messages: [
      { id: '100', text: 'aaa', author: { id: '1' }, receiver: { id: '2' } },
      { id: '101', text: 'bbb', author: { id: '2' }, receiver: { id: '1' } },
    ]
  },
  {
    chatName: 'Name of user ID 3', messages: [
      { id: '102', text: 'ccc', author: { id: '3' }, receiver: { id: '1' } },
    ]
  }
];
```

How can I achieve this with Lodash?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about lodash, but you can use plain js - `reduce` and `map` to get that structure

```js
const messages = [{
    id: '100',
    text: 'aaa',
    author: {
      id: '1'
    },
    receiver: {
      id: '2'
    }
  },
  {
    id: '101',
    text: 'bbb',
    author: {
      id: '2'
    },
    receiver: {
      id: '1'
    }
  },
  {
    id: '102',
    text: 'ccc',
    author: {
      id: '3'
    },
    receiver: {
      id: '1'
    }
  },
];

function groupByPair(arr) {
  return [
    ...arr.reduce((a, b) => {
      let {
        author,
        receiver
      } = b;
      let s = [author.id, receiver.id].sort().join('-');
      a.set(s, a.has(s) ? a.get(s).concat(b) : [b]);
      return a;
    }, new Map)
  ].map(e => ({
    chatName: 'Name of user ID ' + e[0].substring(e[0].indexOf('-') + 1),
    messages: e[1]
  }));
}
console.log(groupByPair(messages));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using either Lodash or Underscore.js:

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(messages, m => _.sortBy([m.author.id, m.receiver.id]));
var formatted = _.map(grouped, (v, name) => ({ chatname: name, messages: v }));
```

You could combine those into a single line, but that seems overly dense to my eyes.

I took the liberty of defining a more complex test dataset, to make sure the edge cases were better covered:

```
var messages = [
  { id: '100', text: 'aaa', author: { id: '1' }, receiver: { id: '2' } },
  { id: '101', text: 'bbb', author: { id: '2' }, receiver: { id: '1' } },
  { id: '102', text: 'ccc', author: { id: '3' }, receiver: { id: '1' } },
  { id: '103', text: 'zzz', author: { id: '2' }, receiver: { id: '1' } },
  { id: '104', text: 'yyy', author: { id: '3' }, receiver: { id: '4' } },
  { id: '105', text: 'xxx', author: { id: '3' }, receiver: { id: '1' } }
```

]

With this data, the code above yields a `formatted` of:

```
[
  { chatname: '1,2',
    messages: [
      { id: '100', text: 'aaa', author: { id: '1' }, receiver: { id: '2' } },
      { id: '101', text: 'bbb', author: { id: '2' }, receiver: { id: '1' } },
      { id: '103', text: 'zzz', author: { id: '2' }, receiver: { id: '1' } }
    ]
  },
  { chatname: '1,3', messages: [
      { id: '102', text: 'ccc', author: { id: '3' }, receiver: { id: '1' } },
      { id: '105', text: 'xxx', author: { id: '3' }, receiver: { id: '1' } }
    ]
  },
  { chatname: '3,4', messages: [
      { id: '104', text: 'yyy', author: { id: '3' }, receiver: { id: '4' } }
    ]
  }
]
```

The major difference with your desired output relates to the `chatname` values. I did not see how you were naming those, so I stuck with Lodash/Underscore's native `groupby` keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`_.groupby`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy). I filter the array first so that you're only left with messages that involve user 1.

```js
const messages = [
    { id: '100', text: 'aaa', author: { id: '1' }, receiver: { id: '2' } },
    { id: '101', text: 'bbb', author: { id: '2' }, receiver: { id: '1' } },
    { id: '102', text: 'ccc', author: { id: '3' }, receiver: { id: '1' } },
];

const filtered = messages.filter((msg) => {
    return msg.author.id === '1' || msg.receiver.id === '1'
});

const groups = _.groupBy(filtered, (msg) => {
    return msg.author.id === '1' ? msg.receiver.id : msg.author.id
});

console.log(groups);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.4"></script>
```